# How can I resolve repeated $_SESSION values, ADD do Cart PHP?

Tags: php, session, cart

I'm creating a shopping cart. Only with session variables. I want something simple, no database, it is only for initial system (later that perhaps use database and logins)

I click in a product and use URL to add in SESSION variable

Exemple Product: Orange

Sent url

```
site.com/?page=buy&add=Orange&type=fruit
```

Then...

```
session_start();

//Create 'cart' if it doesn't already exist
if (!isset($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'])){ $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] = array(); }

if (isset($_GET['add'])){
//Adding an Item
//Store it in a Array
$ITEM = array(
    //Item name     
    'name' => $_GET['add'],
    'type' => $_GET['tipo'],

    //Item Price

    );
```

For print, I use:

```
$itemType = ""; 
foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $itemNumber => $item) {
 if($itemType == $item['type']) {
   // skip...don't print again
 } else { 
    echo $item['type']; 
 }
 echo $item['name']; 
 $itemType = $item['type'];
}
```

however, I have a problem. If I add a fruit, then a food, then a fruit:

Print:

```
Fruit:
      Banana
      Banana
   Food:
      Meat 
   Fruit:
      Apple
```

However, it´s possible to not repeat the "banana" banana?

Print:

```
Fruit:
      Banana
      Apple
   Food:
      Meat x
```

Answer (score 1):

**`array_unique`** — Removes duplicate values from an array
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Example:

```
$items = array(
    'key1' => 'orange',
    'key2' => 'banana',
    'key4' => 'orange',
    'key5' => 'lemon',
);

// first print_r
print_r($items);

$items = array_unique($items);

// second print_r
print_r($items);
```

Output of the first print_r:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => orange
    [key2] => banana
    [key4] => orange
    [key5] => lemon
)
```

Output of the second print_r:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => orange
    [key2] => banana
    [key5] => lemon
)
```

Comment: I try to create like this, but is not working

$result= array(
    //Item name     
    'name' => $_GET['add'],
    'type' => $_GET['tipo'],

    //Item Price

    );

$ITEM= array_unique($result);